# Send JSON data as a string to AJAX from Java Servlet for Datatables

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to AJAX/Javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to

1) through JS/AJAX, call a Java Method in my servlet that generates JSON data from a DataBase

This is what I have so far for calling the method on load. The servlet method is the auto-generated doPut(httpServletRequest etc) in the servlet with the mapping /DAOserv.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callJavaServlet() {

    }
    window.onload = callJavaServlet;
</script>
```

2) Once that method generates the JSON (I have already completed the step where the method calls the DB, gets the result set, and generates the JSON), I need the string of JSON data to be sent back to the AJAX as a response, so it can be parsed into a datatable: http://www.datatables.net/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `response.setContentType("application/json")`, write JSON string to the response, then using request dispatcher forward your request back. A callback `success` function should handle the JSON object. Don't forget to flash response, because it's buffered and also useful to turn off cache with headers.

Comment: Could you post an example of what the AJAX code could look like? Thanks!

Comment: Here the [example](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html) and [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/jquery-autocomplete-ajax-json-example.html).